# add navigation bar programmatically to a tableviewController (segue push or modal )

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to programmatically add a navigationBar to a tableViewController :

[image: Example screenshot:]

When I come from a *PUSH* Segue the builder adds a navigation bar with navigation items, like I want.

But the problem is that when i come form a *MODAL* Segue I try to add a bar with code like this:

```
UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -260, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:naviBarObj];
UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed)];
UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];

UINavigationItem *navigItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Navigation Title"];
navigItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem;
navigItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelItem;
naviBarObj.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: navigItem,nil];

....

- (void) cancelButtonPressed { }
- (void) doneButtonPressed { }
```

But nothing appears... No top bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

naviBarObj's frame ypoint is -260, maybe this is making nothing appear.